# Action to be taken on trolls on the site

Tags: discussion, spam

I would like to bring to the attention of community that the attacks of trolls and spammers is increasing daily on all the posts.

Our only option so far is rejecting the edits or deleting comments.

I would like to keep this post as a discussion for what are steps taken so far and what could be done to prevent this in future.